# cumulant of infinite sum of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-analysis

Could you help me the following question?

Let $X_i$ are identical independent random variables. Putting $Z:=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i$. Which conditions do we have
$$k_n(Z)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}k_n(X_i),$$
where $k_n(Z)$ is the $n$-th cumulant of $Z$. How to prove this identity or any book mentions to this result?
Thank you very much!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant If you have a sum of independent random variables, the equality always holds for a finite sum. So if the sum to infinity exists, this equality should always hold. However I just doubt if $Z$ is properly defined. Summing infinite many of i.i.d. random variables will "explode" in some sense (you need to define convergence in what sense), unless they are constant 0.